# how to changed useSWRMutatuion to useSWR

Tags: reactjs, use-swr

In useSWRMutatuion I have a trigger field, but I have not it in useSWR, what can I use instead of trigger?

```
  const { data: jobsData, trigger: jobsTrigger } = useSWRMutation(
    formJobsUrl(
      sinceDate,
      currentPage,
      comment,
      authorName,
      instrument,
      userData.profile.email
    ),
    updateFetcher
  );
```